# Hiding odd rows in a table on click event

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Problem Statement**

> Write JavaScript code hideOddRows.js that attaches to the button click event and hides the odd rows of the table when clicked.

**Expected Output**

> [image]

When you click on "Hide Odd Rows":

> [image]

---

**Solution**

```js
/* hideOddRows.js */
document.querySelector('[name=HideRows]').onclick = hideRows;

function hideRows(){
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('hide');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(element){
        element.style.display = "none";
    });
    return true;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hide odd rows</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="background-color:#8F9779;width:200px;height:30px;">
        </div>
        <hr style="width:200px" align="left">
        <table border="1" >
            <tr class="hide" >
                <td width="40" height="20">row 1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="40" height="20">row 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hide">
                <td width="40" height="20">row 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="40" height="20">row 4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hide">
                <td width="40" height="20">row 5</td>
            </tr>
        </table><br>
        <button type="button" name="HideRows">Hide Odd Rows</button>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="hideOddRows.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Questions**

1. I could not manage to place `script` tag in `head` due to DOM loading issue. How do I improve this solution to place `script` tag in `head`?
2. Can I improve the HTML code?

**Note:** I've yet to learn jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your JavaScript is OK, but beware of writing code where you can get away without it.  In this case, there is a [CSS3 `:nth-child()` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child)<sup>1</sup> that lets you select odd rows without tagging them manually with `class="hide"`.

You just have to trigger the CSS rule when the button is pressed.  Note that if you want to select one specific element in a document, it's better to mark it using `id="…"` and select it using `document.getElementById(…)` — that's exactly what it is designed to do, and browsers will optimize ID lookups to be as fast as possible.

```js
/* hideOddRows.js */
document.getElementById('HideRows').onclick = function hideRows() {
    document.getElementsByTagName('table').item(0).className = 'odd-rows-hidden';
}
```

```css
table.odd-rows-hidden tr:nth-child(odd) {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hide odd rows</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="background-color:#8F9779;width:200px;height:30px;">
        </div>
        <hr style="width:200px" align="left">
        <table border="1" >
            <tr>
                <td width="40" height="20">row 1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="40" height="20">row 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="40" height="20">row 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="40" height="20">row 4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="40" height="20">row 5</td>
            </tr>
        </table><br>
        <button type="button" id="HideRows">Hide Odd Rows</button>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="hideOddRows.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Caveat: requires Internet Explorer ≥ 9.  If you need to support older versions of IE, you'll probably want [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/).

Answer (score 0):

> 1. I could not manage to place script tag in head due to DOM loading issue. How do I improve this solution to place script tag in head?

Placing the `script` tag in the header is not a necessity of HTML, in fact, I often put my `script`s at the bottom of my `body` tag.

> 2. Can we improve html code?

Yeah, we can.

> ```
>         <tr class="hide" >
>             <td width="40" height="20">row 1</td>
>         </tr>
>         <tr>
>             <td width="40" height="20">row 2</td>
>         </tr>
>         <tr class="hide">
>             <td width="40" height="20">row 3</td>
>         </tr>
>         <tr>
>             <td width="40" height="20">row 4</td>
>         </tr>
>         <tr class="hide">
>             <td width="40" height="20">row 5</td>
>         </tr>
> ```

Instead of using `class="hide"`, you can iterate over the elements and count the index.

---

`return true;` is unnecessary because you don't do anything with the result.

---

Instead of `Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements`, you can evoke `forEach` directly on the nodelist, as long as you attach the additional call to `Array.prototype.slice.call`.

I would suggest to remember that for cases where you make frequent document retrieval calls, simplifying document calls comes in very handy:

For example, one of my simplifications for jQuery-like selection:

```
function $$(selector, el) {
    if (!el) { el = document; }
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(el.querySelectorAll(selector));
}
```

Which would let you make a call like:

```
$$('.postTitle')
```

and iterate over it like an array.

---

### All together:

All together, it would look like:

```
document.querySelector('[name=HideRows]').onclick = function(){
    Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('td')).forEach(function(element, index){
        if (index % 2 !== 0){
            element.style.display = "none";
        }
    });
}
```

Additionally, you should call things like in `.onclick = hideRows` before it's defined, if the function was anonymous, that would cause a bug. It's a good habit to get into.

Comment: In your final code, you use the class `hide` which is given only to the odd rows, and then check for `(index % 2 !== 0)`. That will only return every second odd row instead of every odd row.

Comment: It is a JavaScript solution, a polyfill is when you replace an unwritten function with its implementation in a different solution/library, for example jQuery has a simpler document retrieval system, which I tend to replace with polyfills to discourage jQuery use